# Finding a point on a line with r

Tags: r, coordinates

Ok, so this might be the most basic question ever but I literally can't find how to do it anywhere!
A line has already been graphed. I've been asked to find what my Y point will be when given that my X coordinate is 6. How do I find my Y coordinate?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fit your data and obtain the intercept and slope. Use it to compute your Y-axis value.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot)

Data <- tibble(`Prosocial Behaviour` = c(0:9),
               `Money` = seq(0,18,2)) # sample data

Fit <- lm(`Prosocial Behaviour` ~ Money, data = Data) %>%
  broom::tidy() %>%
  pull(estimate) # obtain the slope and intercept

#this takes the form of Y = c + mx
Y <- Fit[1] + Fit[2]*6 # since you want to find Y given x = 6
```

Comment: Is it really that much work? I don't need it plotted. All I need is the value of Y when X is 6. I mean, I can just eye it out but feels like it'd be great to be able to real quick and exact be like, "what if we gave them $6 dollars to spend, what will their prosocial behavior be then? Ok, How about 7?" Just looking for a command like, 'identify(6, y)', or something like that. Maybe xy.coordiante?

Comment: I've edited it to contain only what you require in that case. I assumed you wanted it plotted on the graph as well. You need only replace the x value in the final step in order to get your Y value, whether it be 6 or 7 or any other number that lies within the range of the original linear fitted data.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps. Fit still is a little tricky for me to understand but I'll go read about the arguments that make it up. Cheers (:

Comment: Or maybe it's 'lm' that I need to look up. I'll check out both.

Comment: now to just figure out the next two lines of that function